# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with keys that fit 2 different rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm stuck with bad data that needs updating in a daily cronjob, coming from a large file import with 6,000 rows.

Table has multiple unique keys, `ems_id`, `pos_id`, `tms_id` (among others)

Problem is that when I execute a bulk insert using, for example:

```
INSERT INTO `venues` (`name`, `ems_id`, `pos_id`, `tms_id`)
    VALUES
        ('CMX Market Cinemas Old Orchard 7', 'aaaa', '1111', 'AAYKQ'),
        ('Cinemark - Dine-in Theatre, Kitchen & Bar', 'bbbb' '2222', 'AAYOB')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `name`=COALESCE(VALUES(`name`), `name`),
        `ems_id`=COALESCE(VALUES(`ems_id`), `ems_id`), 
        `pos_id`=COALESCE(VALUES(`pos_id`), `pos_id`), 
        `tms_id`=COALESCE(VALUES(`tms_id`), `tms_id`)
```

Then because these rows might already exist from a previous import with mixed up keys:
name, ems_id, pos_id, tms_id
xx, aaaa, 2222, AAYKQ
yy, bbbb, 1111, AAYOB

it will pop the error `Duplicate entry '2222' for key 'pos_id'` when trying to update the first row, as this key was already attributed to another row in a previous cronjob import containing invalid data (or 2 rows were merged).

I can't figure out a way to deal with that other than `ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE`, however I can't do that as the data needs to be updated. Is there a way to update on duplicate and fall back to ignore if key exists, or fail silently and keep inserting the rest of the rows?

(Using MySQL 5.7)

Comment: i was wondering about creating a composite unique key as the merge of all the relevant ones to determine the unique field. That could help. Don't know exactly how the precedence is taken between the unique indexes but you should give it a try

Comment: Oh, instead of using a key per column, using a key that spread across multiple columns? Hmm.. could work, I'll have to draw diagrams to see if it could cause issues but that's a good idea!